# Conflict between jQuery plugin LavaLamp and jQuery cycle

Tags: jquery, cycle, lavalamp

I am having problems with what I suspect is a conflict between jQuery plugin LavaLamp and jQuery plugin cycle. The lavalamp worked well until I added the cycle all script

URL for the working lavalamp menu is http://www.eastover.plus.com/consultantnet

URL for the lavalamp menu with jQuery cycle is http://www.eastover.plus.com/consultantnet/slideshow.html

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're including the jQuery script files more than once. Specifically, what's causing your problem is that you're loading jQuery once *after* the LavaLamp plugin has been loaded, thereby overwriting the definition of `$` that had been extended with a plugin.

```
<!-- jQuery is first included here; $ is defined -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="sitefiles/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sitefiles/easing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sitefiles/easingfix.js"></script>

<!-- then your LavaLamp plugin is included here; $.fn.LavaLamp is defined -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="sitefiles/lavalamp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sitefiles/imagecycle.js"></script>
...

<!-- Now, later on, jQuery is included again; $ is overwritten
     and $.fn.LavaLamp is lost -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great advise, everything behaves just fine now, thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 lines which include jquery.js. You can have only 1.
Also you have a wrong naming in this line: `<ul id="1" class="lavaLamp">`. You can rename it to something like `id="menu1"`.